# Help showing this integral is positive.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I would some help on showing that the following integral is positive: Fix $1\leq p < \infty$ and let $(a,b) \in (0.5,1)^2$

$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 a(p+2)|(a,b)|^p \Big(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\Big)^{p} - p|(a,b)|^{p+2}(a-x)\Big(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\Big)^{p-2}dydx
$$

**Context:** I am trying to show that the quotient $$\frac{|(a,b)|^{p+2}}{\int_0^1\int_0^1 |(x,y) - (a,b)|^pdydx}$$ achieves its maximum at $(a,b) = (1,1)$. So, I took its derivative with respect to $a$, which resulted in the integral above (numerator only), and now I'm trying to show it is positive, i.e. the quotient is increasing as $a$ goes to 1. Something analogous for $b$ will allow me to conclude.

I know that the maximum happens at $(1,1)$ for $(a,b) \in [0.5,1]^2$ by using a graphing calculator. [See Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hbzyhm5vov)

Comment: Hmm, I have to disagree. The numerator is to the power of p+2 which guarantees that no singularity will be created. In fact, the +2 is to account for the dimension and, the graph I linked shows you have a nice continuous and bounded function.

Comment: Indeed, my answer does not resolve your comment. But here is another perspective: The double integral is on the denominator only, not over the entire quotient. So the case (x,y)=(a,b) does not causes any issues as for others points (x,y) the double integral will generate positive quantities. 
Sorry, I don't mean to be pushy, I really just want to consider all possible perspectives.

Comment: I truly don't see a singularity of the form $1/r^2$ in the denominator. The integrand is a continuous function (metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$) over a compact domain $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, thus, bounded. How would the integrand lead to $+\infty$?

Comment: O, I see what you mean now! My error (probably because the equation is small-printed in the text... OK, bad excuse). Anyhow, the precise allowed range of $p$ was a side issue of course.

Comment: 'No worries, no worries! It was an important side issue in fact! It's great to take the problems to an extreme so we understand it better. I will put the coefficient in large print XD

Comment: What does the notation $|(a,b)|^p$ mean? If it's the Euclidean norm, why not use $|(x-a,y-b)|^p$ as well?

Comment: $|.|$ stands for the Euclidean norm, yes. So, $|(a,b)| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: @Kzards Indeed the range of $p$ is pretty important for your integral. As explained in my answer below it only starts giving problems once $p$ is around 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prove that the derivative w.r.t. $a$ is positive, because it has zeroes and regions where it is negative.
It's still possible that your quotient has its maximum in the desired corner $(a,b)=(1,1)$. For an extremum
somewhere inside the unit square we would need the derivatives w.r.t. $a$ and $b$ simultaneously zero, and
I don't immediately see such points... But since the question was about the $d/da$ integral, we'll show here
that it can become negative. This happens for $p$ larger than approximately $4.49$. We first split it into two parts:
$$
I = I_1+I_2, \quad \mbox{with:}
$$ $$
I_1 =  a\ (p+2)\ |(a,b)|^p \ \int_0^1 \int_0^1\Big(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\Big)^{p} dy\ dx
$$ $$
I_2 =  -p\ |(a,b)|^{p+2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1(a-x)\Big(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\Big)^{p-2}dy\ dx
$$

For $I_2$ we can write the intgrand as a derivative w.r.t. $x$ (because it obviously comes from a derivative w.r.t. $a$) which makes the $x$ integration trivial:
$$
I2 =  -p\ |(a,b)|^{p+2}\  \int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{-d}{dx}\Big(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\Big)^{p}dy\ dx
$$
$$
  =  p\ |(a,b)|^{p+2}\ \left. \int_0^1\Big(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\Big)^{p}dy \ \right|_{x=0}^1
$$
Now we can shift the variables and write:
$$
I_1=
 a\ (p+2)\ |(a,b)|^p \int_{-a}^{1-a} dx \int_{-b}^{1-b} dy\ \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{p/2}
$$
$$
I_2 =
  p\ |(a,b)|^{p+2} \left.  \int_{-b}^{1-b} dy\   \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{p/2}
        \  \right|_{x=-a}^{1-a}
$$
We first do the $y$ integral, which is needed for both $I_1$ and $I_2$:
$$
 I_y =  \int_{-b}^{1-b} dy\   \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{p/2} =
$$ $$
= | x|^{\ p} \left\{b\ \ _2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{p}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{b^2}{x^2}\Big) - (b-1) \ \
    _2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{p}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{(b-1)^2}{x^2}\Big) \right\}
$$
The hypergeometric functions are only needed for the general case with non-integer $p$. To get
a simpler result we'll now look at $p=6$, which is in the problem region, and gives:
$$
 I_y^{(6)} =\left((b-1) b+x^2+1\right) \left(2 (b-1) b x^2+(b-1) b ((b-1) b+1)+x^4\right)+\frac{3
    x^2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}
$$
By evaluating this in $x=1-a$ and $x=-a$ we find $I_2$  as:
$$
I_2^{(6)} =
  -6\ |(a,b)|^{8} \ \frac{2 a-1}{5}  \Big[15 \Big((2 (a-1) a+3) b^2-2 (a-1) a b+
$$ $$
\quad\quad\quad\quad  + (a-1) a ((a-1) a+2)+b^4-2
    b^3\Big)-30 b+13\Big]
$$
To get $I_1$ we do the $x$-integral, which for $p=6$ gives us:
$$
I_1^{(6)}= 8 a\ |(a,b)|^6 \ \Big\{
a^6-3 a^5+3 a^4 b^2-3 a^4 b+6 a^4-6 a^3 b^2+6 a^3 b-7 a^3+ 
$$ $$
+3 a^2 b^4-6 a^2 b^3+12 a^2 b^2-9 a^2
    b+\frac{28 a^2}{5}-3 a b^4+6 a b^3-9 a b^2+
$$ $$
    + 6 a b-\frac{13 a}{5}+b^6-3 b^5+6 b^4-7 b^3+\frac{28 b^2}{5}-\frac{13
    b}{5}+\frac{24}{35}\Big\}
$$
Now we can plot the original $I=I_1+I_2$ for $p=6$:
[image: Derivative]

In the plot, the blue plane is added to indicate zero, so it is clear that a whole region has a negative value. To be more precise we can look at the function at the $a=1$ edge, which gives just a 12th-order polynomial in $b$:
$$ I^{(p=6)}_{a\rightarrow 1} =
 \frac{(b^2+1)^3}{35}  \left(175 b^6-630 b^5+1260 b^4-1540 b^3+1162 b^2-518 b+101\right)
$$
The negative region is created by the 6th order factor of this polynomial, it is the region where $0.544892 < b < 0.880778$.
As mentioned, this failure to have positive $d/da$ everywhere does not rule out that we'll still find the maximum at $(a,b)=(1,1)$ for the original quotient of the question: $$ Q =\frac{|(a,b)|^{p+2}}{\int_0^1\int_0^1 |(x,y) - (a,b)|^pdydx}.$$
Here's a plot of $Q$ for $p=8$, where the derivative has an even larger negative region, but still the maximum appears to be in the $(1,1)$ corner:

[image: quotient]

**PS: Derivation with Wolfram Engine** of the $y$-integral goes as follows:

```
   As = Assumptions->{a>1/2,b>1/2,a<1,b<1,p>1,x>-1/2}
   Iy = Integrate[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]^p, {y,-b,1-b}, As]
```

with the result:

```
                                                                      2
              p                               1    1     3    (-1 + b)
Out[2]= Abs[x]  (-((-1 + b) Hypergeometric2F1[-, -(-) p, -, -(---------)]) +
                                              2    2     2        2
                                                                 x

                                            2
                           1    1     3    b
>      b Hypergeometric2F1[-, -(-) p, -, -(--)])
                           2    2     2     2
                                           x
```

And it can then be integrated w.r.t. $x$, using

```
Int = Integrate[Iy, {x,-a,1-a}, As]
Ixy = FullSimplify[Int, As]
Q   = (a^2+b^2)^(p/2+1) / Ixy
<<JavaGraphics`
Plot3D[Q /.p->9.12345, {a,1/2,1}, {b,1/2,1},
  AxesLabel->{a,b,"Q"}, LabelStyle->Directive[Bold]]
```

Which allows plotting for any value of $p$, but gives a very long expression for the integral $I_{xy}$:
$$
\frac{1}{(p+1) (p+2)}\ \left\{
b (p+1) a^{p+1} \  _2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{p}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\Big)+b a^{p+1}
\  _2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2} (-p-1),-\frac{p}{2};\frac{1-p}{2};-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\Big)-(b-1) (p+1) a^{p+1} \ 
_2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{p}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{(b-1)^2}{a^2}\Big)-(b-1) a^{p+1} \  _2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2}
(-p-1),-\frac{p}{2};\frac{1-p}{2};-\frac{(b-1)^2}{a^2}\Big)+b (p+1) (1-a)^{p+1} \ 
_2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{p}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{b^2}{(a-1)^2}\Big)+b (1-a)^{p+1} \  _2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2}
(-p-1),-\frac{p}{2};\frac{1-p}{2};-\frac{b^2}{(a-1)^2}\Big)+(a-1) (b-1) (p+1) (1-a)^p \ 
_2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{p}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{(b-1)^2}{(a-1)^2}\Big)+(a-1) (b-1) (1-a)^p \ 
_2F_1\Big(\frac{1}{2} (-p-1),-\frac{p}{2};\frac{1-p}{2};-\frac{(b-1)^2}{(a-1)^2}\Big)- 2 \sqrt{\pi }
\left(b^{p+2}+(1-b)^{p+2}\right) \Gamma \Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{p}{2}\Big) 
\left/ \ \Gamma \Big(-\frac{p}{2}\Big) \right.  \right\}
$$
while the plot for $p=9.12345$ in the example looks more or less identical to the $p=8$ case from the earlier plot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I must say though that this contradicts a little the numerics I have on this problem. So I will accept the answer but it will take me sometime to verify your computations and mine as well. If I find anything worth mentioning I'll certainly add to the discussion. In the meantime, could you ellaborate on what is your definition of hypergeometric functions? Say, for p natural, for example.

Comment: I'll add the derivation with Mathematica, where the hypergeometric is defined as: 
https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/02/ , probably the same as here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function (and of course nothing beats the old-school Abramowitz and Stegun "Handbook": https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/page_556.htm ).

Comment: But I should add that for the discussion of positivity it is not important to use the $_2F_1$ functions. Not even helpful, in fact. Just using an even integer value for $p$ will turn the $(x^2+y^2)^{p/2}$ integrand into a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, and after that all integrations and other actions are just high-school mathematics on polynomials (albeit of somewhat high order...)